# creating a strong password [Python]

Tags: python, function

Need to create a function that validates my password strength having trouble with the third question.

1. Both entered passwords are identical.
2. The password is >= 8 characters in length.

3.If the first and last characters of the password are alphabetic then the first character of the password must be a different alphabetic letter to the last character of the password regardless of case.  e.g 1st char is A so last char cannot be A or a.

```
def validate_password(first_pwd, second_pwd):
    #Checks if password are same
    if first_pwd == second_pwd:
        #Checks if password is greater or equal to 8 characters
        if len(first_pwd) >= 8:
            #Checks if last and first character are alphabetic 
            if first_pwd[0].islower() and first_pwd[-1].isupper() or first_pwd[0].isupper() and first_pwd[-1].islower():
                return True
            else:
                return False


print(validate_password("Abcd1234","Abcd1234"))
```

How do i ignore the digits at the end of the password and look at the nearest alphabetic letter which would be the d.

Comment: While this question has _technically_ been answered... a far better approach would be to use an established library like [zxcvbn-python](https://github.com/dwolfhub/zxcvbn-python) if you want to actually check password strength. What you have here is extremely arbitrary and will allow such excellent passwords as `'aaaaaaab'`, `'password'`, `'11111111'`, and `'username'`.

Comment: @mikuszefski You're attributing arguments to me that I did not make. All I did was point out how comically bad _this_ specific idea of password strength is; unless you disagree with _that_, I don't think you and I have any disagreement.

Comment: there are other attributes such as There are no more than 2 vowels in the password and The password has at least 1 alphabetic character in upper case and 1 alphabetic character in lower case. I just didn't feel the need to post them because they have been solved I was just having trouble with Question 3.

Comment: @kungphu true! Basically, my comment holds for the OP then. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to solve it with a regex. This checks if the first occurrence of a letter equals (case-insensitively) the last occurrence of a letter.

You have to adapt the regex or the if clause if you really just want to check the first char of the string or the last one.
You also can do an extra check to see if the last char in the pwd equals the last letter in the list *chars* below.

```
import re

def validate_password(first_pwd, second_pwd):
# Checks if password are same
if first_pwd == second_pwd:
    # Checks if password is greater or equal to 8 characters
    if len(first_pwd) >= 8:
        # get only the letters of the password
        chars = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]', first_pwd)
        # compare first and last occurrence of letters in pwd
        if chars[0].islower() and chars[-1].isupper() or chars[0].isupper() and chars[-1].islower():
            return True
        else:
            return False


print(validate_password("Abcd1234","Abcd1234"))
```

I also think, it might be enough only to check

```
if chars[0].upper() == chars[-1].upper(): # optional if needed: and first_pwd[-1].upper() == chars[-1].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but as someone who tries to continually improve at python it's recommended to write out the words instead of using abbreviations.

also you rother functions to verify the password strength are being checked only if the password was the same as the previous, so make sure you take length greater than 8 out of the first check

Things worth looking at would be:

islower, isalpha [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

with lower() [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

and I recommend youtubing regex because it's a tough concept imo

```
import re

def validate_password(first_password, second_password):
    if first_password == second_password:
        # Cannot be the previous password
        return False

    letters = "".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", first_password))
    first_letter = letters[0]
    last_letter = letters[-1]
    if len(first_password) >= 8:
        if first_letter.lower() == last_letter.lower():
            # First character can't be the same as last character
            return False
        else:
            # Every test passed
            return True
    else:
        # password too short
        return False

print(validate_password("Abcd1234","Abcd1234"))
```